# How to dynamically create Image for Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped

Tags: image, graphics, infragistics

I have an application that displays leave and absences using an Infragistics UltraMonthViewMulti user interface control.

I have several type of absences that have different colours.  I have successfully created a draw filter that shows a half day triangle on the appropriate day using the following code.

```
    If (day.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) = 0) Then
        drawParams.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(Image.FromFile("..//..//redTriangleHalfDay.png"), day.Rect)
        Return False
    End If
```

The above code requires a PNG file in the appropriate color in the project.  I would like to create these colored images dynamically in code and avoid having a large number of PNG files.

Is this possible?

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

James O'Doherty

Answer (score 2):

Maybe another solution for your task (using again DrawFilter) could be if you replace your images with another type of symbols/colors. Instead of drawing images, you could draw triangle, cirlces, lines, arcs and so on, if you are using for example:

```
Graphics gr = ultraMonthViewMulti1.CreateGraphics;;
        gr.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.Red), new Point[] { new Point(10, 10), new Point(20, 20), new Point(10, 30), new Point(10, 10) });
```

By this way (using three points) you could draw a triangle. Also you could use other draw methods. For example:
gr.DrawCurve, gr.DrawEllipse, gr.DrawLine, gr.DrawPie

Feel free to write me if you have any questions